# Receive function fails to get image

Tags: image, zend-framework2

I am working on multiple file upload code is not showing any error

```
public function imagenewAction()
    {
         $form = new ImageNewForm();
         $form->get('submit')->setValue('Submit');
         $request = $this->getRequest();
         // die('checko');
         if($request->isPost())
         {

           //  die('checko');
            $nonFile = $request->getPost()->toArray();
            $File    = $this->params()->fromFiles('file');
            $data = array_merge_recursive($request->getPost()->toArray(), $request->getFiles()->toArray());
            $form->setData($data);
            if ($form->isValid()) 
            {
                 //New Code
                $dataNew=array('','image','image1');
                for($i=1;$i<=2;$i++)
                {
                $addressProof = $data[$dataNew[$i]]['name'];
                $addressProofextension = pathinfo($addressProof, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                                       // $addressProofimg = $addressProof . $i . "." . $addressProofextension;
                $addressProofimg = $addressProof;
                                        //$verificationdocuments->setdocphotocopy($addressProofimg);
                $adapter = new \Zend\File\Transfer\Adapter\Http();
                $adapter->setDestination('public/img/upload');

                $adapter->addFilter(new \Zend\Filter\File\Rename(array(
                            'target' => 'public/img/upload', 
                            'overwrite' => true
                            )), null,  $addressProofimg);
                if(!$adapter->receive($addressProofimg))
                {
                     print_r ( $adapter->getMessages (), 1 );
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "Image Uploaded";
                }
                }


            }
         }
         return array('form' => $form);
    }
```

It is giving blank error messages and not uploading images please help me to get away with this I am stuck from last 2 days